# roundcube webmail plugins configuration

Tags: configuration, roundcube

- I have strange experience with roundcube plugins. 
  when i am installing one plugin the old plugin that already enabled getting disabled by default.
- I enabling plugings in config file.
- For example when i enable global address book plugin ACL plugin that already enabled getting disable by default.If some one experience this problem and fixed it please help me. I am using roundcube webamil ver 1. 0
- amazon ubuntu instance mail server ( postfix,dovcot,mysql )

Answer (score 0):

I figured it my self instead of adding plugins separately have to add all plugins in
this way.
$config['plugins'] = array('password','globaladdressbook','newmail_notifier','managesieve');

then only plugins will be activate else only 1 plugin will be activate.